# ImageIO does not parse valid .png correctly?

Tags: java, image, imagemagick, javax.imageio

I have a function in Java that uses `ImageIO.read()` to read a file and detect if its fully transparent:

```
private static boolean isFullyAlpha(File f) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(f);
    for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
            if (((img.getRGB(x, y) >> 24) & 0xFF) != 0) {
                println( f.name + " " + ((img.getRGB(x, y) >> 24) & 0xFF) + " " + x + " " + y)
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If I try to read a very simple file that was created with ImageMagick's convert function by cropping an image it returns that the first pixel of this image has 255 alpha (not transparent at all), whereas it works for other images.

The file that is wrong with ImageIO:   https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9186429/imageTest/mountainMap41.png

Is Java's ImageIO buggy? If yes what library could parse this image correctly? Image editors like Paint.NET or Gimp interpret this image correctly.

Note: A file correctly parsed by this function:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9186429/imageTest/mountainMap305.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the PNG files is that `mountainMap305.png` is indexed (color type palette) using a `PLTE` chunk, and adds transparency to the palette using a `tRNS` chunk containing palette indexes.

`mountainMap41.png` on the other hand is grayscale (color type grayscale), and adds transparency to all pixels, using a `tRNS` chunk containing grayscale values. The latter is not supported in the current `PNGImageReader` from Oracle (neither is `tRNS` with RGB values). Only full alpha channel is supported for grayscale or RGB.

You could possibly fix this yourself, by changing the image to a suitable image type with alpha, then looking at the image metadata and replace all pixels matching this color. But I'm not sure if that will be correct, if the values in the image are already gamma/color corrected...